Limit of airdrops per day and problem with airdrop program
I'm new to development of Solana and I tried to create AirDrop program. I'm getting problem with amount of SOL that I can request. I run program 3 times and after that I got message that I exceeded my limit. Moreover the program is not airdropping and I don't know why the balance doesn't change. This is the whole program:
  Connection,
  PublicKey,
  clusterApiUrl,
  Keypair,
  LAMPORTS_PER_SOL,
} = require("@solana/web3.js");

const wallet = new Keypair();

const publickey = new PublicKey(wallet.publicKey);
const secretkey = wallet.secretKey;

const getWalletBalance = async () => {
  try {
    const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"), "confirmed");
    const walletBalance = await connection.getBalance(publickey);
    console.log(`Wallet balance: ${walletBalance}`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

const airDropSol = async () => {
  try {
    const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"), "confirmed");
    const airdropSignature = await connection.requestAirdrop(
      publickey,
      2 * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL
    );

    const latestBlockHash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();

    await connection.confirmTransaction({
      blockhash: latestBlockHash.blockhash,
      lastValidBlockHeight: latestBlockHash.lastValidBlockHeight,
      signature: airdropSignature,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};

const main = async () => {
  getWalletBalance();
  airDropSol();
  getWalletBalance();
};

main();

To run the program I enter node index.js

There is a strict limit for the amount you can airdrop per day, so those errors are expected. And you're likely not seeing the balance updates because you're not awaiting the async functions properly. Try doing:
const main = async () => {
  await getWalletBalance();
  await airDropSol();
  await getWalletBalance();
};

